# Unable to Ensemble average using matlab

Tags: matlab, bioinformatics

I have attempted to ensemble average my ecg data(ecg waveform) but I am unable to do so. This code works perfectly for generated cosine waves:

Codes using cosine wave

```
%test simple ensemble average
%Generate a signal ’s’ as a sum of two cosine signals with different 
%frequency using the following command
n=0:399; %num of samples
f1=3000;
f2=5000;
fs=20*12000; %sample freq
s1=cos(2*pi*f1*n/fs);
s2=sin(2*pi*f2*n/fs);
s=s1+s2; %signal
figure(2);subplot(4,1,1);plot(n,s); 

%Suppose we have 50 repetitive measurement of the signal ’s’ each added by
%random noise N(0,sqrt50)
%These 50 measurements are generated as:

S=repmat(s,50,1);           %50 copies of the signal s
RN=sqrt(0.5)*randn(50,400); %50 random noise signals of length 400 samples
MS=S+RN;                    %add random noise to each signal s 

%Show two of the 50 measurements, number 17 and 32
figure(2);subplot(4,1,2);plot(n,MS(17,:));
figure(2);subplot(4,1,3);plot(n,MS(32,:));

%Compute the average (ensemble averaging) of the first 9 measurements
MS9=MS(1:3,:); %select the first 3 column measurements in MS
MS9
y9=mean(MS9); %averaged signal
%show the averaged signal
figure(2);subplot(4,1,4);plot(n,y9);
```

For my ECG data it returns as "**Index exceeds matrix dimensions**." Which I believe may due to the way I imported my ECG data from csv.

```
%test code
clear all;
clc;

%open data
fid = fopen('Data.csv');
%read data frm CSV
readData = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f','HeaderLines',1,'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
%my extract
x = readData{1,2}(1:1000,1);

%save data in vector form
test_data=[0,0,0,0]
 for j = 1:length(x)
     test_data(j) = x(j);
 end

fs = 960; %sampling frequency
N = length(test_data);
n=0:N; %num of samples
t = [0:N-1]/fs;
close all;
figure (1)
plot(t,test_data)
test_data

% Compute the average (ensemble averaging) of the first 10 row measurements
MS10=test_data(1:10,:); %select the first 10 measurements in MS
y9=mean(MS10); %averaged signal
show the averaged signal
figure(2);subplot(4,1,4);plot(n,y9);
```

As the cosine wave data are stored as :

[image]

But the ECG data is stored as : [image]

Info on Data.csv
[image]

Output for :

```
%test_data = readData{2}(1:10000);
%MS10=test_data(1:10,:);
```

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: Where did you use `test_data`?

Comment: test_data=[0,0,0,0]
 for j = 1:length(x)
     test_data(j) = x(j);
 end
fs = 960;
N = length(test_data);
n=0:N; %num of samples
t = [0:N-1]/fs;
close all;
figure (1)
plot(t,test_data)
test_data
Compute the average (ensemble averaging) of the first 10 measurements
MS10=test_data(1:10,:); %select the first 10 measurements in MS
y9=mean(MS10); %averaged signal
show the averaged signal
figure(2);subplot(4,1,4);plot(n,y9);

The above code did not work for my ECG data (test_data) since the data is stored in a different way compared to the cosine data.

Comment: Ok I appreciate it. Could you edit your post to include the code?

Comment: Done. This I believe is due to the line MS10=test_data(1:10,:); %select the first 10 measurements in MS as my ECG data have no rows. I wonder how to store them using rows and columns accordingly. My data is from the 1st column of a CSV file. 

Please provide a link to a sample code on Ensemble averaging for ECG data if you find any. Thanks

Comment: You defined `test_data` as a 1D vector in the for loop, and later you tried to index the vector with a 2D index, and this is the problem. Could you shine some light on what `Data.csv` is, or at least explain what is `x` (data class, internal structure, etc)

Comment: Exactly. Added the info in the edited attachment. Therefore I need to find a way to convert this 1D vector to 2D vector and perform Ensemble averaging. Or is there a way to perform ensemble averaging on 1D vector ? This is where I stuck and unable to find sample codes online.

Comment: First of all if you only need the second column then it should be `x = readData{2}(1:4)`. Please change your code and see what happens.

Comment: That seem to work well. cool. Attached the output in the previous picture.
Next ?

Comment: Yes change your code to `x = readData{2}(1:4)` and run.

Comment: That doesnt seem to work as I'm not getting the average waveform. I am only getting a single number for the average (y9). And data.m file also popped up. Attached the picture.

Comment: isn't a single column of data what you wanted? `mean` of this data is expected to be a single value, as it is the mean of all the numbers.

Comment: If thats the case, to perform ensemble averaging. I must divide my waveform into frames , store them seperately in multiple 1D vector, align them and then compute for mean ? is this how to get the ensemble average of an ECG ?\